# Laravel Update DB with array from views

Tags: laravel

i'm doing a simple project but having some difficulties with updating my database with values that I get from a form. The project is having a list of movies and when you click on one it would take you to a page with more details. Theres a button which you can update the details of that movie. I'm trying save whatever details are made to the relevant index of the table using the id. I can't seem to get it to work though. I did something similar when creating a new entry but having some difficulty updating the values of a specific movie/page. Thanks for any help!
Route:

```
Route::get('catalog', 'App\Http\Controllers\CatalogController@getIndex');

Route::get('catalog/show/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\CatalogController@getShow');

Route::get('catalog/create', 'App\Http\Controllers\CatalogController@getCreate');

Route::get('catalog/edit/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\CatalogController@getEdit');

Route::post('catalog/create', 'App\Http\Controllers\CatalogController@postCreate');

Route::put('catalog/edit/{id}','App\Http\Controllers\CatalogController@putEdit');
```

Controller:

```
public function getEdit($id)
{
    return view('catalog.edit', ['arrayPeliculas' => Movie::all()]);
}
public function getCreate()
{
    return view('catalog.create');
}

public function postCreate(Request $request)
{
    $Movie = new Movie;
    
    $Movie->title = $request->title;
    $Movie->year = $request->year;
    $Movie->director = $request->director;
    $Movie->poster = $request->poster;
    $Movie->synopsis = $request->synopsis;

    $Movie->save();

    return redirect()->action('App\Http\Controllers\CatalogController@getIndex');
}
public function putEdit(Request $request, $id)
{
    $Movie = new Movie;
    
    $Movie[$id]->title = $request->title;
    $Movie[$id]->year = $request->year;
    $Movie[$id]->director = $request->director;
    $Movie[$id]->poster = $request->poster;
    $Movie[$id]->synopsis = $request->synopsis;

    $Movie->save();

    return redirect()->action('App\Http\Controllers\CatalogController@getIndex');
}
```

Edit page:

```
<form method="PUT">
            {{ method_field('PUT') }}
        {{-- TODO: Protección contra CSRF --}}
            {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="form-group">
           <label for="modificar">Modificar Pelicula</label>
           <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control" value="{{ $arrayPeliculas[$id]->title }}">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
           {{-- TODO: Completa el input para el año --}}
           <label for="Año">Año</label>
           <input type="text" name="year" id="year" class="form-control" value="{{ $arrayPeliculas[$id]->year }}">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
           {{-- TODO: Completa el input para el director --}}
           <label for="Director">Director</label>
           <input type="text" name="director" id="directo" class="form-control" value="{{ $arrayPeliculas[$id]->director }}">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
           {{-- TODO: Completa el input para el poster --}}
           <label for="Poster">Poster</label>
           <input type="text" name="poster" id="poster" class="form-control" value="{{ $arrayPeliculas[$id]->poster }}">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
           <label for="synopsis">Resumen</label>
           <textarea name="synopsis" id="synopsis" class="form-control" rows="3" >{{ $arrayPeliculas[$id]->synopsis }}"</textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group text-center">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="padding:8px 100px;margin-top:25px;">
               Añadir película
           </button>
        </div>
        </form>
```

I tried a few other things like`->update` but I can't seem to get it to work properly.

Comment: Laravel's documentation tells you much than you need about CRUD operation, please do a research first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To update an existing model, first `find()` it.

```php
public function putEdit(Request $request, $id)
{
    $Movie = Movie::find($id);
    
    $Movie->title = $request->title;
    $Movie->year = $request->year;
    $Movie->director = $request->director;
    $Movie->poster = $request->poster;
    $Movie->synopsis = $request->synopsis;

    $Movie->save();

    return redirect()->action('App\Http\Controllers\CatalogController@getIndex');
}
```

Using the update function should also work then:

```php
public function putEdit(Request $request, $id)
{
    $Movie = Movie::find($id);

    $Movie->update([
       'title' => $request->title,
       'year' => $request->year,
       'director' => $request->director,
       'poster' => $request->poster,
       'synopsis' => $request->synopsis,
    ]);

    return redirect()->action('App\Http\Controllers\CatalogController@getIndex');
}
```

You could really simplify it with some Laravel magic like Route Model Binding...

```php
Route::put('catalog/edit/{movie}','App\Http\Controllers\CatalogController@putEdit');

...

public function putEdit(Request $request, Movie $movie)
{
    $movie->update($request->all());

    return redirect()->action('App\Http\Controllers\CatalogController@getIndex');
}
```

Comment: I see, that router model binding seems pretty cool. It's still not working for me though. When I click on submit it seems that the information doesn't save and just populates the fields with the old data again. Is there maybe something wrong with the code from the edit page?

Comment: Found the issue, it was due to <form method="PUT"> and changed it to <form method="POST"> and left methodfield as PUT